# Signals termination handler and cleanup actions

Tags: c, signals, handler, termination

I have to manage the follows signals: `SIGHUP`, `SIGINT`, `SIGQUIT`, `SIGTERM`
The code below is an example with `SIGHUP`:

```
int sock_ds, acc_sock_ds; //TCP sockets

void shutdown(int sig){
    close(sock_ds);
    close(acc_sock_ds);
    raise(sig);
}

/*Sets the disposition of a signal
 * Returns 0 on success, -1 on error */
int sig_disp(int sig, void (* handler)(int), int flag){
    struct sigaction sa;
    memset((char *)&sa, 0, sizeof(sa));
    sa.sa_handler = handler;
    sa.sa_flags = flag;
    sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
    return sigaction(sig, &sa, NULL);
}
int main(){

    /*...*/

    /*--- Signal management ---*/
    sigset_t set;
    /*sigset filling with all signal*/
    if(sigfillset(&set) == -1){
        fprintf(stderr, "Signal set fill error\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /*...*/ 

    if(sigdelset(&set, SIGHUP) == -1){
        fprintf(stderr, "Signal set action error\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /*...*/

   /*Changing signals disposition*/
   if(sig_disp(SIGHUP, shutdown, SA_RESETHAND));

   /*...*/

   /*Remaining signals are inserted into process signal mask (blocked) */
   if(sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, &set, NULL) == -1){
       fprintf(stderr, "Process signal mask action error\n");
       exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }

   /*...*/
}
```

My idea is to reactivate the signal's default handling, which is to terminate the process and re-raise the same signal after cleanup operations.

How can i pass `sig` to shutdown function with `sa.sa_handler = handler;`?

Furthermore what are the cleaning actions commonly taken in these cases? My scenario is mono-threaded server with TCP socket and some opened files.

Answer (score 1):

There is **no need** to close sockets, files, whatever or free memory on exit. The OS will do that anyway, you are just wasting time doing something twice.

To terminate just use

```
exit(0);
```

To reset a signal handler to the original, instead of setting to NULL the last parameter to sigaction you must pass a pointer that will be set with the address of the previous handler.

When you change the handler using *signal*, it will return the pointer of the previous handler

Answer (score 0):

When you say 'manage the following signals', what are you trying to achieve?

If it is just to do some custom cleanup upon receipt of signals that would normally terminate a process, you could use a call to [atexit](http://linux.die.net/man/3/atexit) to register a cleanup function.

Comment: Yes i have only to do cleanup and termination but that must be done from the signal handler

Comment: Because this kind of termination must occur only with a termination signal.

Comment: Fabio, what kind of termination are you referring to? The default handler for signal such as `INT` and `TERM` are to gracefully shutdown the process. This means to close all file descriptors and exit properly. Signals are still involved, you just don't have to deal with them for a straight-forward situation.

Comment: I don't know. that is a didactic implementation of a TCP mono–threaded server in which I have to manage termination signals. At this point I can't imagine why.

Comment: The default behavior of signals is to cause ["Abnormal termination of the process"](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/signal.h.html) and therefore the handlers registered via `atexit` are *not* invoked.